How to render React Amplify StorageImage Component only after React has retrieved all images from S3?
I have a functional component that calls getAllImageFilePathsFromS3Bucket() to get a list of all image file paths currently in the S3 bucket and assigns it to a string array called "images". I then map each of the file paths in "images" to Amplify's StorageImage Component (https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/storage/storageimage) path property to retrieve and display each image.
This works great but I am noticing that for roughly a second or two the UI is displaying the broken image icon before it successfully loads the images. (see the below screenshot)
How can I only display the StorageImage component when it has finished calling to get each image or prevent this behavior?
I did try converting to a class component and leveraging ComponentDidMount() as per Rendering react component after api response, but it produced the same behavior.
import React, { FC, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { list } from '@aws-amplify/storage'
import { StorageImage } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react-storage';

async function getAllImageFilePathsFromS3Bucket() {  
 let filepaths: Array<string> = [];
 const result = await list({ path: 'public/' });
 let listOfS3Items = result.items;
 listOfS3Items.forEach((x) => {
   if (x.size)
     filepaths.push(x.path);
 })
   return filepaths
}

interface PhotosProps { }

const Photos: FC<PhotosProps> = () => {

const [images, setImages] = useState<string[]>([]);

 useEffect(() => {
   getAllImageFilePathsFromS3Bucket().then(x => {
   setImages(x);
  });
 }, []);

return (
     <>
      {
        images.map((file) => {
          return (
            <StorageImage
              width="100%"
              height="100%"
              objectFit="cover"
              objectPosition="50% 50%"
              alt="photo-item"
              path={file} key={file} />
             )
           })
          }   
       </>
       );
 }

  export default Photos;



I ended up setting validateObjectExistence={false} on StorageImage, which seemed to improve the performance a little
